# how to get the result from the server side using the html.beginform?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html.beginform

I need to get the result from the server side. But i using the the HTml.Begin form. My sample code is given below

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("actionname", "contollerr", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
 {

 }

 public ActionResult actionname(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
 {
  message = "your load in failed";
  return Json(new { success = false, message });   
 }
```

How get the result data from the controller?

Comment: Are you uploading a file through ajax?

Comment: no i just upload the file via html.beginform

Answer (score 0):

you are not using ajax, so this code won,t work, you need something like this, validation summary: I assumed the action that generated the form view and the action the method is being submitted to have same name.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("actionname", "contollerr", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
 {
   @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
 }

 public ActionResult actionname(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
 {
  message = "your load in failed";
  ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, message );
  return View();   
 }
```